# Interpretation of entropy equation

Tags: measure-theory, discrete-mathematics

The following equation calculates the entropy for $m$ objectives:

$$H = - \sum_{k_1=1}^{a_1} \sum_{k_2=1}^{a_2}\cdots\sum_{k_m=1}^{a_m} \rho_{k_1k_2\cdots k_m} \ln(\rho_{k_1k_2\cdots k_m})$$

The entropy for one single objective is calculated as:

$$H = - \sum_{k_1=1}^{a_1} \rho_{k_1} \ln(\rho_{k_1})$$

I can't really understand how the entropy is calculated with more than a single objective as shown in the first equation. Is it similar to the following equation?

$$H = - \sum_{k_1=1}^{a_1} \rho_{k_1} \ln(\rho_{k_1})  \sum_{k_2=1}^{a_2} \rho_{k_2} \ln(\rho_{k_2}) \cdots \sum_{k_m=1}^{a_m} \rho_{k_m} \ln(\rho_{k_m})$$

If they are not the same can you please clarify it to me?

Comment: You could for example just re-encode your objectives as one objective with a larger set of possibilities and then the first formula is equivalent to the 1-objective case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy